# Not able to synchronize process using Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I was testing my skills over `Thread` behavior. When I implemented `Runnable` interface and `synchronized` the run method, I got absolute result. But, when I extend `Thread` class, the result was unpredictable. Below are the two cases. I think, threads in both cases use same resource.

**case 1 `Runnable`**

```
class Counter{
    int count;
    public void doCount(){
        count=count+1;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
public class One implements Runnable{
    Counter counter = new Counter(); // common object to be shared with two threads
    public void run(){
        synchronized (this) {
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                counter.doCount();
            }   
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        One one = new One();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(one);// using same resource 'one'
        Thread t2 = new Thread(one);// using same resource 'one'
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000); // to give both threads time to complete
        System.out.println(one.counter.getCount());
    }
}
```

**case 2 `Thread`**

```
class Counter{
    int count;
    public void doCount(){
        count=count+1;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
public class One extends Thread{
    Counter counter; //common object to be shared with two threads
    One(Counter counter){
        this.counter = counter; 
    }
    public void run(){
        synchronized (this) {
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                counter.doCount();
            }   
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        One o1 = new One(counter);// using same resource counter
        One o2 = new One(counter);// using same resource counter
        o1.start();
        o2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000); // to give both threads time to complete
        System.out.println(counter.getCount());
    }
}
```

for case 1, I am getting output 20000 every time. but for case 2, I am getting random values every time. Why is it so? case 2 is also using same resource among two threads, then why do they stop getting `synchronized`. can any one explain this.. I am going nuts!!

Comment: Ask yourself: what is `this` in `synchronized(this)` in the first case and what is it in the second case.

Comment: ok wait, asking.. I mean thinking..

Comment: Because .. you are not synchronizing on the counter but on something else that has multiple instances?

Comment: I can help you with the first case, the `this` refers to your `One one = new One();`. But what about in the second case?

Comment: no @Kayaman please explain more please..:(

Comment: @JSK please try to answer Kayaman's question. It's a very important question, and you should be able to answer it, especially if you're dealing with advanced complex stuff like threads. What is `this`?

Comment: @JBNizet , ok in first case `this` is One as @kayaman answered, and I think in second case also `this` is One..please don't get angry..am I right? see because in case 2 also it is inside One class

Comment: You're absolutely right. `this`is the instance of One. How many instances of `One`do you create in the first case, and in the second case?

Comment: @JBNizet yes yes I got it..Ooh laa laa.. wow I am so stupid. But now I will never forget this. yes there are two instances of One in case two each has its own copy of counter..

Comment: They don't have their own copy of `counter`, they share the single instance. But you're not synchronizing on `counter`, you're synchronizing on `this` which in your second case is `o1` and `o2`.

Comment: Nope. That's not the problem. There are indeed two instances of One, but both share the same counter. The problem is that the first thread synchronizes on the first instance of One, and the second thread synchronizes on the second instance of One. So they access a shared resourse (counter), but synchronize on different locks. So entering the synchronized block in the first thread doesn't prevent the other thread of entering its synchronized block.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, put the synchronization mechanism as close to the resource (where the critical sections are) as possible. Neither this One nor that One is a good choice.

Comment: @Kayaman and JBNizet , now I got your point. my brain is now neatly wired..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`synchronized (this)` is faulty. In this case, you have 2 instances: o1 and 02. `synchronized (counter)` should work but is not an ideal solution.

Ideally, just for testing, I would use a private lock.

```
class Counter{
    final Object lock= new Object();
    int count;
    public void doCount(){
        synchronized (lock){
            count=count+1;
        }
    }
    public int getCount(){
        synchronized (lock) {
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

A better approach than `sleep` would be to use `Thread.join()`

Comment: synchronizing doCount() onluy doesn't make the Counter thread-safe. getCount() must be synchronized, too, on the same lock.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right; I didn't post the full code

Comment: that's why I like stack overflow community so much for their out of box approach to solve things.

Comment: why introduce lock object, when synchronized keyword on both methods would work as well?

Comment: @mlecz I mention that synchronized (counter) will work as well. I just prefer the second one

Comment: @mlecz just found more reason for private lock in effective Java item 82

Answer (score 2):

In this example I would just synchronize on the counter instance instead of putting the synchronization inside the Counter class as suggested by others. This keeps the Counter class simple and unaware of any potential threading issues, which only arise when the class is used by multiple threads.

So the code would be:

```
public class Counter {
    int count;
    public void doCount() {
        count=count+1;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}

public class CountRunner implements Runnable {
    Counter counter; 
    public CountRunner(Counter counter){
        this.counter = counter; 
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized (counter) {
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                counter.doCount();
            }   
        }
    }
}

public class CountThread extends Thread {
    Counter counter; 
    public CountThread(Counter counter){
        this.counter = counter; 
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized (counter) {
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                counter.doCount();
            }   
        }
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        countRunnerTest();
        countThreadTest();
    }

    public static void countRunnerTest() {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        CountRunner countRunner = new CountRunner(counter);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(countRunner);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(countRunner);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        System.out.printf("CountRunnerTest result=%s", counter.getCount());
    }

    public static void countThreadTest() {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        CountThread t1 = new CountThread(counter);
        CountThread t2 = new CountThread(counter);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.printf("CountThread  result=%s", counter.getCount());
    }

}
```

Comment: now that I have understood my doubts, this also seems to be cool and precise way

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, underlying "this" object refers to two different instances of One class i.e, o1 and o2. The for loop is running independently having object monitor lock on two different instances, hence obviously the counter modification in un-synchronized here.

Usually standard data structures throw ConcurrentModificationException in such a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `synchronized (this)` it takes lock on the object you are calling your method.

In Case one you create

```
One one = new One();
```

and pass to each method so both are using same object as lock.

In case 2 you are creating two object and both are using different object as lock.You can use counter as lock instead of this ,that will solve your problem.

```
 One o1 = new One(counter);// using same resource counter
 One o2 = new One(counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first of all you should know the differences between implementing runnable and inheriting from thread [here](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/05/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java-example.html?m=1).
Then, read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for understanding **clearly** the porpuses of adding synchonized.

Anyway, check the `this` inside the synchronized function. In the first case it's related to `One one = new One(One)`... And the second `One one = new One(One)` It's related to itself. Both are synchonized, but the first one synchonizes with the first instance of one. However, the second one synchonizes with the second instance of one. Try to use a lock It should work.

Comment: @JSK Glad you've liked them.